# Unable to launch Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I installed  Android Studio a month ago and it worked successfully and  I was using **windows 7(64bit)**  Then I setup a new **windows 7 (32bit)** and  I reinstalled the **JDK** and **Android Studio** and  I even downloaded the latest version of  **Android Studio** but it didn't work.

First, a message pop up to set **environment variables**  which I did, then i I opened Android Studio again and another message appeared :

> **Could not find main class com/intellij/idea/main**

[image]

I searched about that problem and found that the solution is to add  **JAVA_HOME** with value

> **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101**

Then, I opened it again and it didn't work and no messages appeared. I tried to run the SDK but an error massage appeared:

[image]

Comment: Just to confirm: Your Java version is same as `jdk1.8.0_101`?

Comment: yes it is 1.8.0_101

Comment: Do you have similar `bit` versions of *Java* and *Android Studio* installed ?
I mean both of the installations should be either *32* bit or *64* bit. A mix-match won't be good!

Comment: Android Studio runs on both 32 and 64 bit ,, and for java i downloaded the latest version on the official website which is 1.8.0_101 for windows 32 bit ,, and if it wasn't 32 it wouldn't have been installed

Answer (score 0):

I just quickly googled for this and it seems that for all the people that have had this issue the solution was to uninstall Android Studio, download the installer again and install it from scratch.

Comment: i did that i even downloaded the latest version of Android Studio as well as java but still having the same problem i don't know is it because of the windows or what

Comment: @mohamedahmed I think that's a windows problem... What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: Well. I am using 64bit on my pc and it installs and runs smoothly... What about changing to 64bits OS?